# NuGet; Transitive Dependencies; Binding Redirect Hell

Tags: c#, nuget, .net-standard-2.0, assembly-binding-redirect

> *.NETCore just litters your disk a lot worse, too many versions, too many assemblies, too many standards and no GAC. Hopefully they'll get their act together sometime soon.* – Hans Passant Aug 17 '17 at 10:37

No, it just keeps getting worse.   : \

Have a .NET Standard 2.0 class library that references Microsoft extension classes.  When we deploy to the server, we get runtime binding exceptions.  My questions first:

1. Why aren't binding redirects being generated for transitive dependencies?
2. Since they're not, how do I come up with a full list to add manually?
3. How does the compiler know what version to redirect to unless it intends for me to deploy the version it compiled against?
4. How do I come up with a list of DLLs to deploy - excluding framework DLLs but including anything that wouldn't be on the server?
5. Is a nuget package broken if the assembly version in `\ref\` is lower than the assembly version in `\lib\`?

**Details:**
We have a class library compiling against .NET Standard 2.0... it references `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json`.

```
MimExtension
 \--Dependendencies
    \--Packages
         \--Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json (5.0.0)
             \--System.Text.Json (5.0.0)
                 \--System.Buffers (4.5.1)
```

System.Buffers resolves to `\.nuget\packages\system.buffers\4.5.1\ref\netstandard2.0\System.Buffers.dll`.  The file version in that directory is 4.6.28619.1, date 2020/02/19.  .NET Reflector shows the assembly version as `4.0.2.0`.

The `\lib\` version of that DLL is `\.nuget\packages\system.buffers\4.5.1\lib\netstandard2.0\System.Buffers.dll`... same file version and date, but the assembly version is `4.0.3.0`.

Compiling the DLL gives me a .dll.config file with binding redirects that I could copy into the consuming application's app.config - but `System.Buffers.dll` and `System.Text.Json.dll` aren't there.  `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json.dll` also isn't there - though another nuget package, `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions.dll`, is.

I'm assuming this means the compiler thinks no redirect is necessary for the DLLs that aren't in there (see question #3).  It makes sense that only DLLs with conflicts across references get added to the binding redirects (if that's what's happening), but conflict or not, our app won't bind to the `\lib\` version of the System.Buffers.dll the compiler uses and RTE's (question #1).

To resolve this I can add binding redirects manually.  But how do I look at all the nuget references in my project and determine (recursively) what version was chosen for each dll?  Short of dumping verbose build output to a text file with some fancy regex and an hour of copy and paste, that is (question #2).

Note:  I can add `<CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>true</CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>` to the .csproj file and get *all* referenced dlls dumped to the output directory - including .NET dlls like `System.Threading.dll` and `System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.dll`- but that still doesn't get me a full list of what versions each one are... especially since I need *assembly* versions, which I can't even display in explorer.

Regarding that... some of the binding redirects generated automatically are for .NET assemblies like `System.Threading`... does VS really expect me to deploy the version of System.Threading I compiled against?  For that dll, I have `newVersion="4.0.11.0"`... our server has assembly version 4.0.0.0, file version 4.8.3761.0.  VS expects me to deploy assembly version 4.0.11.0, file version 1.0.24212.01 (wtff?!?).  The 4.0.11.0 version pulled down by nuget is dated 2019/12/26... the 4.0.0.0 server version is dated 2021/01/21.

I'm guessing that's a Core vs. Framework versioning wtf - but binding redirects don't care.  The app that will load our library is .NET Framework 4.8... am I supposed to deploy the System.Threading 4.0.11.0 dll with my app, or manually change the binding redirect and let it load the server's version?  It's absolutely ludicrous that a core DLL has a higher assembly version than its newer .NET Framework counterpart (question #addingnewonesasigo).

So when we're referencing nuget packages, how do we know what needs deployed and what doesn't (or worse, shouldn't be)? (question #4)  I feel like the build process should copy dlls that aren't part of the framework/won't be in the GAC to the output directory - but there's nothing TIAO to indicate that in the nuget package specs.

Regarding #5... shouldn't the dlls in a nuget package have the same version in the `\ref\` and `\lib\` folders?  The breakdown in `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json` is in `System.Text.Json`... S.T.J's .nuspec lists a .NET Standard 2.0 dependency to `<dependency id="System.Buffers" version="4.5.1" />`.  So why would the `System.Buffers.dll` nuget cache have different versions in `\ref\` and `\lib\`?  Shouldn't they both be either 4.0.2.0 or 4.0.3.0?

There are a **lot** of questions out there on this - even some specifically to System.Buffers.  But nobody has resolved this satisfactorily (that I can find) for a class library.  I'm going to try adding a scratch website to the solution and reference the library - just to see whether .NET gets the necessary dlls/redirects in place for its only love:  Web

**Update** 
I manually added a binding redirect to 4.0.3.0 for System.Buffers... and immediately got the next mole to whack:  `Could not load file or assembly 'System.Numerics.Vectors, Version=4.1.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies`

And so it will go, until we find a way to list everything that VS probed.  And without 100% regression coverage, there's no guarantee we won't miss something when we deploy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compiling the library for specific platforms pulls the dependent DLLs into the bin folder.  This makes sense in retrospect - compiling for .NET Standard is only meaningful when the target platform isn't known and won't be chosen by the developer of the library.  That scenario requires a centralized package manager.

Targeting for .NET 4.8 (highest version currently supported by MIM) gave us the DLLs in the bin directory and set binding redirects in the config file.

That said, the System.Buffers.DLL version issue only went away because the .NET 4.8 dependencies were defined correctly.  The Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json .nuspec indicates a different assembly version than the dll that gets downloaded when compiling for .NET Standard 2.0.  I don't know if that's an issue with the references when the .NET developers compiled the nuget package or an unavoidable artifact of nuget packaging itself.

Answer (score 0):

For an executable, `dotnet publish`; and ship the resulting folder is always correct.

But for a dll compiled against .net standard; I've only had success building a nuget package and referencing it and letting the compiler (whole package thereof) figure out what final dlls the project needs. You can make a nuget package with `dotnet pack`.

I have never needed binding redirects to link .netstandard to .net framework.

Comment: Generating a nuget package doesn't include the dlls... a project that references the nuget package I generate might pull the referenced dlls down to the output directory - but I haven't found anything that pulls what I need into the class library's output folder.

Comment: @JamesKing: When you build the final executable that references the nuget package, only then will it pull in the correct dlls. Things like System.Text only have reference dlls; no dll from it will be in the final target.

Comment: And that's my problem... this is an extension DLL for Microsoft's Identity Manager - the library I'm building is the final application.  Maybe that's my answer - I need to leave my referenced libraries (our internal common libraries) targeted at .NET Standard, but pick a platform for the extension DLLs themselves.

Comment: @JamesKing: Build a test harness exe; import the nuget package and watch it haul in everything at build time.